# How to use same Class"XY" for both ios and watchos3 with swif3

Tags: frameworks, swift3, xcode8, watchos-3, watchapp

I tried to use a Custom Framework but it is not importing in the WatchApp Extension ->interfacecontroller.
In the ios App the Import statment work correct.

my question is : 
how to use same classes in both targets(ios and watchos)

Answer (score 0):

Creating a framework is indeed the recommended way to go. Just make sure your framework supports the arm7k architecture and also is compiled against the watchOS SDK.